# tablesorter: Getting height of at table in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Colleagues,

I am trying to compute the height in pixels of a Tablesorter object in my JavaScript code. The Tablesorter object is called "myTable" and I am trying the following approach:

```
var height = $('#myTable').height();
```

Alternatively I've tried:

```
var height = $('#myTable').css("height");
```

My HTML is:

```
<div>
<table id="myTable">
<thead><tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>A</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td>2</td></tr>
</tbody></table></div>
```

Both return a value of zero, but I know the table is about 100 pixels high. Is there a way to dynamically determine the table height from within the JavaScript code?

EDIT:  This does not appear to be a Tablesorter problem. I get zeroes for height when I just create the table as HTML an run the jQuery commands referenced above.

Thanks!

Dan

Comment: Can you post the html details? Then someone can help

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't work. Are you sure you are calling your code after the DOM is fully loaded?

Comment: I have modified the request to include the HTML. Thanks!  I am using Chrome.

Comment: what is the CSS for this table?

Comment: There is none. Thanks!

Comment: there's something wrong with your code. when the JS is being called? try putting it inside the jquery's document.ready event. http://jsfiddle.net/nWb5j/87/